# Why doesn't my Java string concatenation work?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

When this code runs, it gets the content of a webpage.

I wanted to concatenate that entire string rather than printing it to the console but when I uncomment the two lines in the code below, `System.out.println(inputLine);` prints nothing (but it worked with the line below commented) and the value `fileText = null`,

where does this error come from?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String fileText = "";
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            //fileText.concat(inputLine);
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
        //System.out.println(fileText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, you are right!. The method `concat` hasn't worked since 1996 and none of the 10 million developers who use Java noticed, good catch. :P

Comment: I will edit the question title to be a little more SO friendly

Comment: Seems like a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076740/whats-the-fastest-way-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-java seems to get at the essence of the question (How do I concatenate a java string) even though the linked question is specific to performance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`String` is *immutable* and [concat()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29) will return a new `String` (check the linked doc), which you're not collecting.

You should make use of a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) to build a string efficiently, and then call `toString()` on that once you're complete to get he resultant String.

e.g.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (....) {
   sb.append("more string data");
}
String str = sb.toString();
```

You *can* append `Strings` e.g.

```
   str = str + "more string data";
```

but it's not very efficient, due to the implementation of `String`. A `StringBuilder` is built in order to perform concatenation efficiently. You can tune a `StringBuilder` via its initial capacity if you have an idea of the size of `String` you're building.

You may see some sources refer to a `StringBuffer`. That's very similar, except it's older and synchronises its methods by default. In a non-threaded environment that's wasteful and the general advice is to prefer `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 8):

`String` is immutable object. You need to reassign the concatenated value to a string object. Simply calling `fileText.concat(inputLine);` will not change the value in `fileText`.

`fileText = fileText.concat(inputLine);`

Simply, `fileText += inputLine;` should work too.

Answer (score 6):

[`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is immutable, so just calling `concat` on a `String` **doesn't** change it: it returns a new `String` with the result.

You can instead re-assign the result: `fileText = fileText.concat(inputLine);`, but since you're in a loop, potentially doing lots of concatenation, it's better to use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to do the concatenations, and get a `String` from the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Also, lines that are comments out .. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Hello you must assign the return value of fileText.concat(String) to a variable. In your case to fileText again.
The solution for you is:

```
fileText = fileText.concat(inputLine);
```

Have a further look at the Java API -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 2):

`String`s are immutable. This means that `fileText.concat(inputLine);` does not change the contents of `fileText`. Rather the `concat()` method returns a new `String` with the expected data. You need to capture this return value to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

change `fileText.concat(inputLine)` to `fileText = fileText.concat(inputLine)`.

Also, initialize `String inputLine = null;`

Answer (score 1):

You should better use `StringBuilder` for that. Something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (...)
    sb.append(line);
```

It's far more efficient than repeated concatenation of `String`s.

Even simpler solution is to use [Apache Commons IO library](https://commons.apache.org/io/), in particular [IOUtils.toString(InputStream,String)](https://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29).